# How to call an imported module by using a string variable for it's name in JavaScript and VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-modules

I have a single file component in VueJS in which I import modules from other files like this:

```
<template>
     //Some code here that call for the function "myFunction" and pass to it an object...
</template>

<script>
    import Task from "../../APIs/Task"
    import Status from "../../APIs/Status"
    
    export default{
        data(){ 
            //Some code here...
        },
        methods: {
            myFunction(someObject){
                <!-- This is the part that does not work. Please see the error message below. -->
                [someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject].someFunctionThatBothModulesHave(someObject.payload)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the error I get in the console:
`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: [someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject].someFunctionThatBothModulesHave is not a function"`

As you can see, it seems that the string stored in someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject is not translated to module name. Instead, the whole expression is taken literally as is.
In other places in my code I call modules' functions dynamically by using the following syntax:
`ModuleName[functionNameAsString]`

The idea is to create an general purpose method that takes both module name and payload as arguments and execute basic CRUD functions on different kind of objects, using dedicated module for each object type for separation of responsibilities.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to call a module using its name from a variable, without using `switch` or `if` statements?

Thank you in advance,
Lior.

Comment: `[someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject]` is an array literal. If you want to access the modules as properties of an object using a dynamic property name, you need to put them in an object.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, this seems to work. I'll update my question with the solution once I'm done testing it. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you might want to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I have. I'm a bit new to posting questions, let alone answers, here, but thank you for pointing out the option :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Bergi suggestion in the comments I was able to call modules dynamically using string variable. The solution was to create an object in my component data where its properties were named the same as the modules and their values were references to the modules themselves. Please see the code example below.

```
<template>
     //Some code here that call for the function "myFunction" and pass to it an object...
</template>

<script>
    import Task from "../../APIs/Task"
    import Status from "../../APIs/Status"
    
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                modules:{
                    Task: Task,
                    Status: Status
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            myFunction(someObject){
            !-- This works! -->
              this.modules[someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject].someFunctionThatBothModulesHave(someObject.payload)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, should the brackets be around just the module name?

```js
someObject[moduleNameAsStoredOnObject].someFunctionThatBothModulesHave(someObject.payload)
```

The way you have it, `[someObject.moduleNameAsStoredOnObject]` is an array containing the module name. So you’re trying to call `someFunctionThatBothModulesHave` on an array.

Comment: Hi Ray, thank you for replying!
This does not seems to work as moduleNameAsStoredOnObject is simply undefined in this context. However, it seems that @Bergi was on to something. I'll post an edit to my question once I'm done testing his suggestion of setting a wrapping object around my modules.